# PHP: Determining Variable Content based on Sentence

Tags: php, function, strpos

I have made a simple weather condition analyser that analyses the weather condition based on a certain website.

My code is:

```
<?php

$V = "Partly cloudy possible thunderstorms with rain";

function getMyString($SentenceSrc)
{
    if (strpos($SentenceSrc,'cloudy') AND (strpos($SentenceSrc,'thunderstorm') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'T-storm')))
        $SentenceVariable = "Cloudy with rainshowers or thunderstorms";
    elseif (strpos($SentenceSrc,'rain') OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Rain')) AND (strpos($SentenceSrc,'thunderstorm') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'T-storm')))
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy with brief rainshowers or thunderstorms";
    elseif (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Sun') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'sun'))
        $SentenceVariable = "Sunny";
    elseif (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Stormy'))
        $SentenceVariable = "Stormy";
    else
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy with brief rainshowers or thunderstorms";
}

$y = getMyString($V);

echo 'hi'.$y;

?>
```

I wish my output to be:

```
hiCloudy with rainshowers or thunderstorms
```

But it is only displaying hi. What is wrong?

Comment: How about returning `$SentenceVariable` from the function?  I.e., `return $SentenceVariable;` as the last line of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your function.

```
function getMyString($SentenceSrc)
{
    if (strpos($SentenceSrc,'cloudy') AND (strpos($SentenceSrc,'thunderstorm') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'T-storm')))
        $SentenceVariable = "Cloudy with rainshowers or thunderstorms";
    else if (strpos($SentenceSrc,'rain') OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Rain')) AND (strpos($SentenceSrc,'thunderstorm') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'T-storm')))
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy with brief rainshowers or thunderstorms";
    else if (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Sun') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'sun'))
        $SentenceVariable = "Sunny";
    else if (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Stormy'))
        $SentenceVariable = "Stormy";
    else
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy with brief rainshowers or thunderstorms";

    return $SentenceVariable;
}
```

**[Working Code.](http://codepad.org/A96R6cAb)**

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$SentenceVariable' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: I placed a return on my function and it didn't work. However, i simply copied and pasted your working code from your link and it works well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the value from your function:

```
function getMyString($SentenceSrc)
{
    if (strpos($SentenceSrc,'cloudy') AND (strpos($SentenceSrc,'thunderstorm') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'T-storm')))
        $SentenceVariable = "Cloudy with rainshowers or thunderstorms";
    elseif (strpos($SentenceSrc,'rain') OR (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Rain')) AND (strpos($SentenceSrc,'thunderstorm') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'T-storm')))
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy with brief rainshowers or thunderstorms";
    elseif (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Sun') OR strpos($SentenceSrc,'sun'))
        $SentenceVariable = "Sunny";
    elseif (strpos($SentenceSrc,'Stormy'))
        $SentenceVariable = "Stormy";
    else
        $SentenceVariable = "Partly cloudy with brief rainshowers or thunderstorms";

    return $SentenceVariable;
}
```